# NullReferenceException when make a PUT request using Flurl

Tags: c#, http, flurl

I'm constructing a Url and making an `PUT` request using Flurl, as follows:

```
using (var client = new Url("myurl"))
    .ConfigureClient(c => c.HttpClientFactory = new CompressHttpClientFactory())
    .WithCookie(new System.Net.Cookie("name", "value", "/", "domain"))
{
    var content = new StringContent("json here", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PutAsync(content)
}
```

But I'm getting an exception when calling `PutAsync`:

> System.NullReferenceException occurred
>     HResult=0x80004003
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     Source=Flurl.Http
>     StackTrace:
>      at Flurl.Http.FlurlClient.ReadResponseCookies(HttpResponseMessage response)
>      at Flurl.Http.FlurlClient.d__28.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Should I use `try / catch` and ignore the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the actual HTTP call is failing to get a response, and Flurl is trying to read the cookies anyway without doing a null check on the response. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/208) and is fixed/ready for the 2.0 release. 2.0 is in [prerelease](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/2.0.0-pre2) right now and I recommend upgrading. It's stable for production use, I'm just not guaranteeing quite yet that the [changes](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/releases) are set in stone.